# format string with wider space between specific chars

Tags: css

How to format a barcode EAN13 string with CSS and add wider space between specific char/digits? Want to add wider space after char 1 and char 7

https://boxshot.com/barcode/tutorials/ean-13-calculator/ean-13-barcode-check-digit.svg

Right now I use this function to format the string

```
function format_barcode_ean13(v){
    return `<div style="display:inline-flex; gap:4px">
    <div>${v.substring(0, 1)}</div>
    <div>${v.substring(1, 7)}</div>
    <div>${v.substring(7, 13)}</div>
</div>`;
}
```

But when using the above function you can't double click on the string to select the entire string. Only the group (flex item) is selected.

I need to be able to apply the wider space between chars and still be able to double click and then select everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `letter-spacing` for individual characters and produce wider gaps after them:

```html
<p>12<span 
style="letter-spacing: 2em;"
>3</span>45<span
style="letter-spacing: 2em;"
>6</span>789</p>
```

This way it will remain a "single word" for double click selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a non-breaking space ( ) between specific characters to create wider spacing without affecting the ability to select the entire string.
Here's an example of how you can format the string using this method:

```
function format_barcode_ean13(v){
return `<div style="display:inline-block;">
${v.substring(0, 1)}&nbsp;
${v.substring(1, 7)}&nbsp;
${v.substring(7, 13)}</div>`;}
```

Comment: When you double click on one part of the string only the "group" is selected